# How to fix LMMS not loading VSTs?

Tags: software, vst

LMMS is basically an OpenSource alternative to FL Studio, and I'm using it on Arch Linux. I tried loading the synth1 VST as described [here](https://lmms.io/documentation/Working_with_VSTs) (and also some other VSTs), but lmms then seems to get stuck at "Loading VST, please wait". Unfortunately there is no console output whatsoever to help me diagnosing the origin, so I'm hoping someone here can help solving this or at least figuring out what's wrong at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately a [known issue](https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/issues/1875) with no known fix. However, simply using the Windows version of LMMS via wine works (though there are some graphical glitches in e.g. synth1's GUI).